# How to create folders and subfolders into a remote FTP server if they don't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ftplib

I need to send the images downloaded from one server to another. Furthermore, I would like to save images in folders organized by date with "year" and "month". Here's an example:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp-server','userftp','*********')
    
file = open('download-torrent-filme.webp','rb')
    
ftp.storbinary('STOR year/month/download-torrent-filme.webp', file)
```

I need to create such folders in case they don't exist on the FTP server. My idea is to store the year and month in a variable and send it. For example:

```
year = date.today().year
    
month = date.today().month
    
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+year+'/'+month+'/download-torrent-filme.webp', file)
```

But I need the folder to be created if it doesn't exist. How can I do this cleanly and simply as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your tasks you can use following 2 functions of the library `ftplib`:

- `nlst()`: returns a list with all files and directory present on the FTP server
- `mkd()`: create a folder on the filesystem of the FTP server.

Try the code below:

```
import ftplib
from datetime import date

str_year = str(date.today().year)
str_month = str(date.today().month)

# here I use exactly your example instruction
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp-server','userftp','*********')
if str_year not in ftp.nlst():
    # year directory creation
    print(f"[1] - {str_year} directory creation")
    ftp.mkd(str_year)
    # year/month directory creation
    print(f"[1] - {str_year}/{str_month} directory creation")
    ftp.mkd(str_year + "/" + str_month)
else:
    if str_year + '/' + str_month not in ftp.nlst(str_year):
        print(f"[2] - {str_year}/{str_month} directory creation")
        # year/month directory creation
        ftp.mkd(str_year + "/" + str_month)
```

---

#### Documentation

- See [this link](https://pythontic.com/ftplib/ftp/mkd) for info about `ftplib`.
- [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) of ftplib.

Comment: looks good, but I need to create a folder inside the other, one with YEAR and inside it with MONTH

Comment: You can check before if exist year and if not create it. After that create inside year month. If year exists check if it contains month and if not create it inside year.

Comment: I'm trying here. thanks :)